# How to get all values of a given custom attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, collection, product-collection

I have a custom product attribute `test_id` which is a text field. I want to get all the values assigned to this attribute within a given product collection.

I found the following way of doing it. But I need to know if there is a better solution.

```
public function getAllTestIds() {
    $allValues = array();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    foreach($collection as $product) {
        $data = $product->getData();
        if(trim($data['test_id']) != '') {
            $allValues[] = $data['test_id'];
       }
   }
return $allValues;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Sukeshini,add groupByAttribute() to get data of unique data and remove null .

```
public function getAllTestIds() {
    $allValues = array();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('test_id', array(
    'notnull' => true,
    ))->groupByAttribute('test_id');

    foreach($collection as $product) {
        $data = $product->getData();
            $allValues[] = $data['test_id'];
       }
   }
return $allValues;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way is:

```
public function getAllTestIds() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('test_id');
    return $collection->getColumnValues('test_id');
}
```

Only selecting the attribute(s) we are interested in, improves collection loading performance. But `getColumnValues()` calls `load()`, so it is still not optimized much.

If you want to avoid loading the whole collection, a hand crafted SQL query is probably necessary.